# When the android Kill the app will onDestroy() method will be called first?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I am a beginner in Android and
I want to know if  i write some code in `onDestroy()` method 
and the user open another app beside this now the `onPause()` and `onStop()` will be called correct ?
then if the android **kill the app** The `onDestroy()` method  will be called first or not ??

Answer (score 0):

As a user navigates through, out of, and back to your app, the Activity instances in your app transition through different states in their lifecycle. The Activity class provides a number of callbacks that allow the activity to know that a state has changed: that the system is creating, stopping, or resuming an activity, or destroying the process in which the activity resides.

For this first, you need to understand the Activity Life Cycle how it actually works.
[image]

For further details check this [page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).